# Should we overload the meaning of configuration settings?

Tags: configuration

Imagine an instance of some lookup of configuration settings called "configuration", used like this:

```
if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration["MySetting"])
{
    DoSomethingWithTheValue(configuration["MySetting"]);
}
```

The meaning of the setting is overloaded. It means both "turn this feature on or off" and "here is a specific value to do something with". These can be decomposed into two settings:

```
if(configuration["UseMySetting"])
{
    DoSomethingWithTheValue(configuration["MySetting"]);
}
```

The second approach seems to make configuration more complicated, but slightly easier to parse, and it separate out the two sorts of behaviour. The first seems much simpler at first but it's not clear what we choose as the default "turn this off" setting. "" might actually a valid value for MySetting.

Is there a general best practice rule for this?

Comment: Unsure if this would be better at programmers.stackexchange.com. It's not intended to be subjective -- it's something we need to resolve in my current work environment.

Answer (score 0):

I find the question to be slightly confusing, because it talks about (1) *parsing*, and (2) *using* configuration settings, but the code samples are for only the latter. That confusion means that my answer might be irrelevant to what you intended to ask. Anyway...

I suggest an approach that is illustrated by the following pseudo-code API (comments follow afterwards):

```
class Configuration
{
    void parse(String fileName);
    boolean exists(String name);
    String  lookupString(String name);
    String  lookupString(String name, String defaultValue);
    int     lookupInt(String name);
    int     lookupInt(String name, int defaultValue);
    float   lookupFloat(String name);
    float   lookupFloat(String name, float defaultValue);
    boolean lookupBoolean(String name);
    boolean lookupBoolean(String name, boolean defaultValue);
    ... // more pairs of lookup<Type>() operations for other types
}
```

The `parse()` operation parses a configuration file and stores the parsed data in a convenient format, for example, in a map or hash-table. (If you want, `parse()` can delegate the parsing to a third-party library, for example, a parser for XML, Java Properties, JSON, .ini files or whatever.)

After parsing is complete, your application can invoke the other operations to retrieve/use the configuration settings.

A `lookup<Type>()` operation retrieves the value of the specified name and parses it into the specified type (and throws an exception if the parsing fails). There are two overloadings for each `lookup<Type>()` operation. The version with one parameter throws an exception if the specified variable does not exist. The version with an extra parameter (denoting a default value) returns that default value if the specified variable does not exist.

The `exists()` operation can be used to test whether a specified name exists in the configuration file.

The above pseudo-code API offers two benefits. First, it provides type-safe access to configuration data (which wasn't a stated requirement in your question, but I think it is important anyway). Second, it enables you to distinguish between "variable is not defined in configuration" and "variable is defined but its value happens to be an empty string".

If you have already committed yourself to a particular configuration syntax, then just implement the above `Configuration` class as a thin wrapper around a parser for the existing configuration syntax. If you haven't already chosen a configuration syntax and if your project is in C++ or Java, then you might want to look at my [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) library, which provides a ready-to-use implementation of the above pseudo-code class (with a few extra bells and whistles).